# How to do reference comparison in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, comparison, equality

In [Equality and Comparison Constraints in F#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsyme/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f/), it said that:

> Note there is no such thing as “reference comparison” (the object pointers used by .NET move around, so the ordering would change). You might implement that by using a unique tag and custom comparison.

How can I use an unique tag for comparison in F# and C#?

Comment: F# doesn't have access to Object.ReferenceEquals? C# cirtainly does. https://msdn .microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd183759.aspx

Comment: I'd assume "unique tag and custom comparison" means "add a property to the object and order by that".

Comment: The article mentions that because the default for nearly all .NET object types is reference equality, F#'s concept of 'comparison' is not supported out-of-box for all .NET object types.

Comment: The 'unique tag' and 'custom comparison' mentioned by the article probably means 'override Equals/GetHashCode' and 'inherit IComparable and/or IComparable(T)`. Which is shown in the example after the statement.

Comment: @Romoku Good point, it's a shame they didn't use "standard" .net terminology like that.

Comment: So to sum up the question about the article: 'comparison' is a feature of F# that does not work with all .NET object types by default because most .NET object types use reference equality and do not implement IComparable/IComparable(T).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to do reference comparison in .NET? How can I use an unique tag for comparison in F# and C#?

Note that in this context, the word "comparison" is being used as distinct from "equality". It describes an *ordering* as opposed to just identity (which *is* supported). .And just as the referenced article says, if you want an ordering, you have to impose it yourself. The compiler can't infer one for you, nor can there be a default "reference comparison" as there is a default "reference equality".

You can apply the `StructuralComparison` attribute to require that a type does in fact implement a comparison (similar to `: comparison` generic constraint), which allows ordering operations to occur. This gives you compile-time assurance from the compiler that your type meets the requirement that the inferred type implements a comparison.

So, how do you do "reference comparison"? You don't! It wouldn't make sense to, just as the article says. You need to use a type that already has a comparison implemented, or e.g. implement `IComparable<T>` for your type, so that it meets the `comparison` constraint.

If you need more help than that, you'll need to be more specific. Post a question that includes a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what *specific* difficulty you are running into, trying to apply the advice in the referenced article to your own code, with a precise explanation of what you've tried, and what you're still having difficulty getting to work.